# Security issues in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, biginsights

I have well working Embedded Pig program which is using PIG 0.7.1 and Biginsights 1.0 . Now I want to execute the same program in a new version of PIg(0.9.1) and Biginsights(1.4). But When i am executing it is showing following errors.

```
 org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=administrator, access=WRITE, inode="user":biadmin:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x
```

FYI ,I am able to read hdfs files using java program. I think there is only problem with PIG. Can any one help me to solve this issue.?

**This is my sample code:**

```
PigServer ps = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE,prt);
    ps.registerQuery("A = load '/user/biadmin/student' using PigStorage() as (name:chararray);");
    ps.registerQuery("B = foreach A generate name;");
    ps.store("B", "user/biadmin/myoutput123");
```